# Is there a Annotation in Apache Camel to load a specific RouteBuilder during a test?

Tags: integration-testing, apache-camel, spring-annotations

Suppose I have several tests on the same RouteBuilder that is configured differently for each test.

Now, a Spring test is supposed to:

- extend something like AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests
- be annotated with @ContextConfiguration(locations="test-context.xml")
- include the RouteBuilder in the context: `<camel:camelContext id="whatever"><camel:routeBuilder ref="routeBuilderUnderTesting" /></camel:camelContext>`

This implies that each test class must have a specific context xml file pointing to the wanted RouteBuilder (that is a version of the RouteBuilder under testing, but configured specifically)

What if I want all the versions of RouteBuilders under testing in the same context xml (or not even that, just annotate them with @Component instead of putting them in an xml) and, in each test, to specify the actual implementation of the RouteBuilder to test?

Is there such an annotation in camel spring test (to tell a test which bean to run as RouteBuilder)?

Answer (score 1):

See this page how to use the `<camel:contextScan/>`
http://camel.apache.org/spring.html

Then you can just annotate your unit test RouteBuilder classes with the Spring @Component annotation.

Comment: did read that documentation, but not enough. but, i think you can autowire the Context in your test and annotate with @Qualifier("mySpecificCamelContext")

Answer (score -1):

Why don´t you use the normal camel TestSupport classses without spring? There you just instantiate the RouteBuilder with new and do not have to care about annotations.